# Trabajar con datos JSON en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Tengo una variable `JavaScript` de la siguiente forma:

```
var datos ={Tabla: 'Principal' , CampoConsulta:['Nombre','Apellido_Pa','Apellido_Ma'], DatosConsulta:['Juan Luis','Perez','Martinez'], TipoDato:['s','s','s'], Val:[1,2,3] };
```

Estos datos los quiero pasar a `PHP` para despues crear una consulta `MySQL`

**Ajax**

```
function busquedaFiltros(){
var data = stringify(datos);
$.ajax({
    url: '../../php/instancias.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {Funcion: 'Filtros', Datos: data},
})
.done(function(data) {
    $("#tbl_TblFil").empty();
    $("#tbl_TblFil").append(data);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
```

}

Pero ya en `PHP` ya no se como trabajar con los datos JSON. Por ejemplo tengo un array dentro de mi objeto `json` y quisiera recorrerlo. He leído varias cosas, pero me dejan con mas dudas que respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando el metodo [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) lo puedes lograr. Esto lo que hace es que convierte el json en un objeto y así puedes acceder sus propiedades como un objeto cualquiera:

```
$datos = json_decode($_POST["DATOS"]);
echo $datos->Tabla

// para acceder a un array lo haces como lo harias con un objeto normal

foreach($datos->CampoConsulta as $campo)
{
  echo $campo;
}
```

Como habras notado, para acceder a los elementos del array se utiliza `$datos->CampoConsulta` ya que ese es el nombre de la propiedad en el json y asi seria para los array `DatosConsultas`, `TipoDato` y `Val`. Si el array contuviese objetos en vez de un array de string, entonces solo tendrias que acceder a las propiedes del mismo:

```
foreach($datos->arrayConObjetos as $value)
{
  echo $value->nombrePropiedad;
}
```

Comment: si quiero acceder a un dato en especifico seria `$datos->CampoConsulta[0];`?

Comment: Sí. Una vez lo conviertas a objeto con el metodo json_decode, puedes acceder a cualquier propiedad como lo haces normalmente en php.